# Probability density function of dependent random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

If $X$ is a random variable with PDF $f_X(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $Y = e^X$. What is the PDF $f_Y(y), y > 0$?

How can I compute the PDF of $Y$ knowing that of $X$ and knowing how $Y$ depends on $X$?

Comment: Such computations are usually easier to do with the *cumulative distribution function*, from which the probability density function can be obtained by differentiating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)dt = P(X\le x).$$ Then for $y>0$ we have $$F_Y(y) = P(Y\leq y) = P(e^X\le y) = P(X\le \ln(y)) = F_X(\ln(y)).$$

Then recall that if $$F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y)  =  \int_{0}^y f_Y(t)dt,$$ we have $f_Y(y)=F_Y'(y) ,$ so $$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy} F_X(\ln(y)) = \frac{1}{y}F_X'(\ln(y)) = \frac{1}{y}f_x(\ln(y)).$$